# Facebook SDK causing 'appDebug' error android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to incorporate Facebook SDK , but Android Studio is giving me errors at compile time.

Here is my error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/junit-4.10.jar')
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar')
compile project(':stripe')
compile project(':FacebookSDK')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.specyci:residemenu:1.6+'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

But this doesn't work, and honestly isn't a good solution. When I remove facebook sdk, my app compiles no problem, but with it nothing works. What am I missing here?

Comment: @jaydroider using that kind of version definition is not recommended. To have fast, reliable and repeatable builds you should provide a specific version for a dependency

Comment: Use this `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'` instead of `compile project(':FacebookSDK')`.

Comment: @WarrenFaith Sir i have made that corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You are over 64K methods in your build because of using so many libraries, enable [multiDex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html), clear unused libraries, remove unused methods with ProGuard or whatever you want, but you have reached the method count limit for a single APK.

Comment: check the latest compile dependency. He already uses multidex

Comment: So you assume instead of asking in a comment?

Comment: Yes, reading his explanation and looking at the error, more than 64K methods issue

Comment: Funny, I can only find a pretty [dedicated error](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) stating the limit is reached. What if I tell you that `finished with non-zero exit value 2` is a pretty generic error and can not be pinned to one specific error case?

Comment: I know this is a generic error, but have you seen the id?

Comment: what id are you talking about?

Comment: If you think so. I have experienced value 2 with different errors as reason.

Comment: First of all: I am not your "dude". Second: Care to state what you mean exactly by "kind of error"? All I see is damn generic.